# Would it be possible to use old VGA wiring in the walls of our home to carry USB data?

Tags: usb, vga, cable, connector

We have an old VGA cable built into our wall. It isn't used any more. But now I need a USB cable, but it is too much effort to build it into the wall. I got an idea to make two reductions USB to VGA, and pass the four USB lines through the VGA cable. Is it a bad idea? Why?

Is there a problem with passing USB wires through an old VGA cable? Nobody seems to sell this kind of "reduction" but there must be many old cables in walls in the world and this can make many lives easier.

The total length of the USB cable needed is about 4 meters, length of the VGA cable is 3 meters. The USB device connected is a webcam (sitting on top of a TV for conference calls). So it would be ~1 meter real USB cable plus ~3 meters through VGA cable.

The power consumption of the webcam is less than 2.5W, because the power is supplied by standard USB port (5V * 0.5A).

Comment: You need to know if the wires are 18 gauge or better, sadly the lower the number the better it is.  I would tape a network cable to the VGA and use the VGA cable to pull in a network cable.  There are RJ45 to USB convertors.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues with what you are trying to do.

(a) USB relies on twisted pair wires to carry the data signals.  VGA cable (typically) does not have twisted pair wires.  But quality VGA cable should have 5 coaxial wires for the RGBHV signals.  Two coax wires *might* substitute for the twisted pair for `D+` and `D-`, although there would be an impedance mismatch (75 Ohms versus 90 Ohms) that would degrade the signal transmissions.

(b) USB has a severe distance limitation (as defined in the USB specifications), whereas VGA distance is whatever you can get away with.
The USB cable length restriction can be increased with the use of a USB (active) cable extender.  While some USB devices can work with a USB extender, there are others that won't/can't due to timing issues.
A USB active extender is the same as a USB hub (but with only a single downstream port).

---

You really haven't provided enough details of the situation.
What exactly are you trying to connect, and what are the total distances?
Even if you had twisted pair in the wall, you might be exceeding USB distance limitations/restrictions. Don't forget to account for the two cable extensions for host-to-wall and wall-to-device.

BTW the proper (electrical) term for what you refer to as a *"reduction"* is (cable) adapter. *"Reduction"* sounds like a plumbing term.

---

Note that there are twisted-pair-to-coax adapters available (for impedance matching), although "coax" implies a BNC connector.
Breakout cables (as below) would be needed to adapt the VGA (HD-15) connector to BNC.

[image]

---

**Addendum**

> The total length of the USB cable needed is about 4 meters, length of the VGA cable is 3 meters. The USB device connected is a webcam (sitting on top of a TV for conference calls). So it would be ~1 meter real USB cable plus ~3 meters through VGA cable.

At 4 meters your situation is only 1 meter (20%) less than the USB 2.0 limitation.  But rather than an extension using the expected twisted pair cable, you would have a inferior situation consisting of baluns (e.g. transformers) to match impedance, and an abundance of interconnections.  Therefore successful operation of the webcam using VGA coax is far from certain.  Acquiring the necessary items is likely to be expensive if not time consuming, so an experimentation may not be feasible or advisable.

Comment: I've added requested details.

Comment: @MílaMrvík -- updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should try it.  USB carries power over the lines which is something VGA wasn't designed to do.  USB 2.0 and up relies on twisted pair wiring as well.

Comment: According to this article the non twisted data cables might be a problem. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-magic-between-data-transfer-quality-improving-when-twisting-wires-on-USB-or-phone-cables

Comment: Power really isn't an issue.  Conductors can simply be combined for more current capacity.  *"USB 2.0 and up relies on twisted pair wiring as well."* -- Misleading.  The USB 1.0 and 1.1. specifications require twisted pair wires.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fire hazard concern here. USB is designed to pass a decent amount of power (although perhaps whatever you're using it for won't do so), and applying that to cabling not meant to carry it is a bad idea. Doing it inside your walls is an even worse idea.

Even if possible, not worth it.

Comment: That is misinformation.  The maximum amount of power over USB 2.0 would be limited to just 2.5 watts, which should not be a concern.  There are cables/wiring rated for in-wall use, aka riser cable.  The actual hazard is not the amount of power carried, but rather the flammability of the wire's insulation.  I.E. could the insulation burn and act as fuel for the fire to travel to another room?  Riser cable has fire-resistant insulation.

Comment: Your reference to USB 2.0 appears to be a non-sequitur. Separately, yes, in-wall cable has flame retardant material, but that's for a different issue -- because you don't want to load your walls up with fuel for a fire any more than necessary. That doesn't make it a less bad idea to risk starting a fire inside your walls by energizing a cable with a source that was never contemplated for it.

Comment: @bigjoec To be fair, outlets handle 120v or more  at 15amps so they are a much higher risk than 20v at a 5 amp max.  Although you still need a certain gauge wire to handle the amps.